# -setNeedsDisplay not getting called to refresh drawRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uikit

I have two methods that get called from within `-drawRect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  {

    if(drawScheduleFlag) {
        [self drawSchedule];
        drawScheduleFlag = false;
    }
    else
        [self drawGrid];
}
```

`-drawGrid` is called at initialization time.  The other method (`-drawSchedule`) is called from this code, which is on the main thread:

```
- (void) calendarTouched: (CFGregorianDate) selectedDate  {

//    NSLog(@"calendarTouched - currentSelectDate: %d/%d/%d", selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, selectedDate.year);
//    NSLog(@"Main thread? %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);

    //  get data from d/b for this date (date, staff name, cust name, time, length, services required)
    //------    stub    -------
    scheduledDate.year = 2012;
    scheduledDate.month = 6;
    scheduledDate.day = 20;
    staffName = @"Saori";
    custName = @"Brian";
    startTime.hour = 11;
    duration = 2;
    servicesReqd = @"Nails";

    drawScheduleFlag = true;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    return;
}
```

I know the code is being executed, but nothing happens to draw the schedule.  Why is `-[self setNeedsDisplay]` not causing the `-drawRect` to be called?

UPDATE:  I have put breaks in so I'm positive it's not being called. The original grid is drawn once; when the user taps a calendar date, -calendarTouched is called and completely executed. The drawScheduleFlag is set to true, and -[self setNeedsDisplay] gets called, but -drawRect does not. It appears that the UIView is not being invalidated (which -setNeedsDisplay is supposed to do), therefore -drawRect is not called.

UPDATE #2:  I have a .xib for a UIViewController with two (2) UIViews in it.  The first UIView takes about 1/3 of an iPad screen, the second UIView takes the bottom 2/3 of the screen.  Each UIView has it's own specific class; the top UIView displays a calendar and is working correctly, capturing touches and changing the date selected.

The bottom UIView is supposed to show the schedule for the date picked in the top UIView.  This is where the problem is.  Since the top UIView is working, I will put up the code for the bottom UIView's class.  It basically draws the schedule grid when -drawRect is first called.  Once the user has selected a day, it is supposed to invalidate the UIView to draw the actual schedule on the grid.

Here is the code for Schedule.h:  http://pastebin.com/NQpj0i07
Here is the code for Schedule.m:  http://pastebin.com/YBbE8y0T
Here is the code for the controller:  http://pastebin.com/nDqBCivj
Note that both pastebin's expire in 24 hours from Jun 28, 5:38 PM PST

Comment: Have you made sure it isn't called? Have you made sure it's only called once? Set a breakpoint. Maybe it is called, but is called again directly afterwards, which then goes to `drawGrid`, which presumably erases the schedule again.

Comment: The phrase "-drawGrid is called at initialization time" sounds suspiciously nasty...

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide a little more code and context. Also, is your view living in a view hierarchy at this point?

Comment: Is the code that calls `-setNeedsDisplay:` on the main thread? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: Hi Richard... yes, it's on the main thread (used -NSLog(@"Main thread? %d", [NSThread isMainThread]); which returned a 1)

Comment: Jerry: this is pretty much the whole context... I'm just starting to draw for this UIView.  There is a view controller with two views in it: one on top the other (the problem child) on the bottom. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216065/how-to-draw-graphic-objects-within-drawrect-at-different-times)

Comment: setneedsdisplay doesn't immediately refresh your screen but does so at the first available moment. It will take a while before it happens

Comment: How long is "a while"?  It's been sitting there for 5 minutes now, and nothing has happened... and I don't think anything is gonna happen... :-{

Comment: Is it possible that between the setNeedsDisplay and the call to drawRect the UIView is getting deallocated? Use logging to see if this is happening.

Comment: OK... I put a NSLog in the -dealloc method for the UIView class where this is happening, and it does indeed appear to be deallocated.  Now, how do I fix this so it doesn't dealloc the UIView?  (btw, I'm using ARC)

Comment: Update your code with a bit more context, or paste a gist of where you are allocating this object and how are you holding reference to it (weak, strong).

Comment: Views that are added to a view hierarchy by `[otherView addSubview:thisView]` should be retained, so unless you're linking to another module that's not using ARC and calling release on it from there, I don't see how you could lose this view object.

Comment: Where's the code for the controller? The controller is the one holding the reference to the view that has the drawRect method, he's the one that deallocates the view. And when you say you have 2 subviews, I assume this view is one and the ivar it has is the other one right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating what I said in the comments, the problem you are having is that your `UIView` subclass object is getting deallocated before the `drawRect` call gets executed, which means that whatever is holding the reference to the object, in this case your controller, is releasing it before you mean to, little issue that sometimes comes up with using ARC.

In the controller code that holds this view you should have something like this declared:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Schedule *scheduleView;
```

And synthesized:

```
@synthesize scheduleView = _scheduleView;
```

And in the controller's `dealloc` method:

```
self.scheduleView = nil;
```

If you're using storyboards, which you appear to not be using since you made a .xib file for this, you should have it hooked up properly. If not simply instantiate it and assign it.

Expanding on what I said before, I'm not sure what you're trying to do but taking a look at your code you are creating the view for a brief moment when the notification gets called and  right there it's getting deallocated because no one is holding a reference to it. By doing what I said and control+click drag from the controller to the view in interface builder and hooking it up it will hold the reference to it, and you'll only have 1 Schedule object created.

After that you'll have to modify your code to work with this instance of Schedule:

```
- (void) testNotification:(NSNotification *) notification  {

    //  was the calendar tapped?
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"calendarUpdated"])  {

        NSDictionary *passedData = notification.userInfo;  //  get passed data
        CFGregorianDate currentSelectDate;
        NSData *data = [passedData objectForKey:@"currentSelectDate"];
        [data getBytes:&currentSelectDate length:sizeof(CFGregorianDate)];

        [self.scheduleView calendarTouched:currentSelectDate];
    }

    return;

}
```

The other option you have if you're not using interface builder to set everything up is the following in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scheduleView = [[Schedule alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubView:self.scheduleView]; // Probably some extra code for positioning it where you want

    // notify me when calendar has been tapped and CFGregorianDate has been updated
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(testNotification:) name:@"calendarUpdated" object:nil ];

}
```

As a final note, considering you're new to iOS development (as we all were) you can go to iTunes and look for Stanford's iPad and iPhone Development course (CS193P) on iTunes U, it's completely free and it will teach you most of what you need to know for developing in iOS.

Comment: There is nothing declared... that might be the problem, yes?  Here is the code for the controller:  http://pastebin.com/nDqBCivj  and here is the code for CalendarView.h, which is the class of the upper UIView.  I see it has what you are referring to; do I have to do something like that to Schedule.h?

Comment: Yep, it's most likely that, you have nothing holding a reference to your view, so it just goes out of memory, declare this in the way I said in the answer and let me know how it goes. Remember to either hook it up in Interface Builder or otherwise instantiate it in the controller and assign it

Comment: See my post above with the reference to CalendarView.h. I will do this tomorrow, since it's time for dinner.  I appreciate your time.  Look for my post after 7 a.m. Pacific Time... thanks again...

Comment: No problem, hope it's really this and it solves your issue :) Saw the line where you instantiate the Schedule view, it's coming into existence and then getting dereferenced right there, hold a pointer to it like I said, or created when you instantiate your controller, hold a reference to it and then call the method on it, since for each notification you are creating a new Schedule object.

Comment: I hate to be asking for too much... but could you point me to a doc where it explains how to create the pointer and hold it?  (I'm relatively new at objective-c this deep, and am a bit confused).

Comment: Let me expand my answer to reflect it better

Comment: 8vius:  thank you, thank you, thank you!  it works now!  I couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to check out the course, you will learn a great deal.